# MySQL repeats resutls when variables used and query changed

Tags: mysql, variables

Strange thing. There is a table:

```
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| date_time       | datetime(3)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
```

With data:

```
+-------------------------+
| date_time               |
+-------------------------+
| 2017-01-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-06 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-09 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-11 00:00:00.000 |
| 2017-01-12 00:00:00.000 |
+-------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That if I query this way:

```
SELECT 
    @date_from := FIRST_VALUE (DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (
        ORDER BY `date_time`
    ) AS `Date From`,

    @date_to := LAST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (
        ORDER BY `date_time`
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS `Date To`,

    @date_diff := TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @date_from, @date_to) AS `Period [D]`

FROM 
    test
WHERE 
    `date_time` 
    BETWEEN 
        '2017-01-02' 
    AND 
        '2017-01-12'            
LIMIT 1;
```

I get result:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| Date From  | Date To    | Period [D] |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-12 |         10 |
+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

As expected but with 3 warnings (each the same sentence):

> Warning | 1287 | Setting user variables within expressions is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider
>   alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s)
>   INTO variables(s)'

And when I change at the end of query one date:

```
WHERE 
    `date_time` 
    BETWEEN 
        '2017-01-02' 
    AND 
        '2017-01-10' -- Changed
LIMIT 1;
```

I get result with the same period as before (wrong):

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| Date From  | Date To    | Period [D] |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-10 |         10 |
+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

But now comes the fun part: If I reply execution of the same query (with end date 2017-01-10) I get proper result:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| Date From  | Date To    | Period [D] |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-10 |          8 |
+------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

@date_diff is later used in other statements but I cut off all the non relevant code.

How to rewrite the select portion so there will be no warnings, and why am I getting wrong Period (@date_diff) at the first query execution but right at its second run? How to solve that?

I'm using MySQL 8. and code queries are run from MySQL CLI client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why they're removing this usage of variables. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
>   undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1`
>   evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

There is no guarantee as to the order of execution of the variable assignments in your `SELECT`, so what appears to be happening in the second query is that `@date_diff` is being computed *before* the value of `@date_to` is updated. The easiest way around this is to remove the variables:

```
SELECT 
    FIRST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time`) AS `Date From`,
    LAST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time` ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS `Date To`,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, FIRST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time`), LAST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time` ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) AS `Period [D]`
FROM test
WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-01-12'            
LIMIT 1
```

Or use a subquery to make it neater:

```
SELECT `Date From`, `Date To`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `Date From`, `Date To`) AS `Period [D]`
FROM (SELECT 
        FIRST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time`) AS `Date From`,
        LAST_VALUE(DATE(`date_time`)) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time` ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS `Date To`
      FROM test
      WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-01-12'            
      LIMIT 1) t
```

Comment: Will the order of variables assignment be in right order if used the alternative way from the warning? `Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'` ? I would like to stick to use variables since further down calculations are a bit messy without them.

Comment: @Jimmix well if you do a series of `SET` statements they will definitely be executed in order. But in general the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT` is not guaranteed. You might want to consider using a stored procedure, or you can continually nest subqueries to force an evaluation order (since nested subqueries have to be evaluated before the outer ones).